# Spark / Scala / SparkSQL dataframes filter issue "data type mismatch"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My probleme is i have a code that gives filter column and values in a list as parameters

```
    val vars = "age IN ('0')"
    val ListPar = "entered_user,2014-05-05,2016-10-10;"
    //val ListPar2 = "entered_user,2014-05-05,2016-10-10;revenue,0,5;"
    val ListParser : List[String] = ListPar.split(";").map(_.trim).toList
    val myInnerList : List[String] = ListParser(0).split(",").map(_.trim).toList

if (myInnerList(0) == "entered_user" || myInnerList(0) == "date" || myInnerList(0) == "dt_action"){
                    responses.filter(vars +" AND " + responses(myInnerList(0)).between(myInnerList(1), myInnerList(2)))

        }else{
          responses.filter(vars +" AND " + responses(myInnerList(0)).between(myInnerList(1).toInt, myInnerList(2).toInt))
        }
```

well for all the fields except the one that contains date the functions works flawless but for fields that have date it throws an error

Note : I'm working with parquet files
here is the error [image: error]

when i try to write it manually i get the same [image: error]

here is how the query it sent to the sparkSQL
the first one where there is revenue it works but the second one doesn't work [image: query]

and when i try to just filter with dates without the value of "vars" which contains other columns, it works
[image: here is the result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my issue is that i was mixing between sql and spark and when i tried to concatenate sql query which is my variable "vars" whith df.filter() and especially when i used between operator it was giving an output format unrocognised by sparksql which is

> age IN ('0') AND ((entered_user >= 2015-01-01) AND (entered_user <= 2015-05-01))

it might seems correct but after looking in sql documentation it was missing parenthesese(in vars) it needed to be

> (age IN ('0')) AND ((entered_user >= 2015-01-01) AND (entered_user <= 2015-05-01))

well the solution is i needed to concatenate those correctly so to do that i must to add " expr " to the variable vars which will result the desire syntaxe

> responses.filter(expr(vars)  && responses(myInnerList(0)).between(myInnerList(1), myInnerList(2)))